# TKinter tkFileDialog.askopenfilename Always behind other windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a simple TKinter file selection dialog with a function that I will use from other scripts and not a wider GUI.

My current code is:

```
# Select a single file and return the full path as a string
def select_file(data_dir):

    chdir(data_dir)

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

    return file_path
```

When I run this the file dialog is always behind other windows. If I have Spyder maximised, it opens behind it so I have to minimise.

There are a few questions related to this, but I've been unable to get any of the suggested code to work, so apologies if this is viewed as a duplicate question.

Ben

Comment: You might want to try _not_ withdrawing the root window. Instead, use `geometry` to move it off screen. I have never needed to try this, but it seems likely that the problem is at least partly related to the fact you've withdrawn the root window.

Comment: I have the same problem. were you ever able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just have to use `root.deiconify()` after `file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()`

But it's a bad idea to create a new `Tk` here.

Comment: Between this and not asking for root.withdraw() I still don't have the window appearing on top. Deleting root.withdraw() has the fringe benefit of leaving a toolbar icon, so you can at least maximise the dialog without minimising Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Use `root.focus_force()` to make the root window on top and the `fileDialog` should also be on top:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

def select_file(data_dir):
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.focus_force()

    return tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir=data_dir)



select_file(data_dir)
```

Comment: Hi - with Spyder maximised the dialog still opened behind it.